# Making google analytics query

Tags: google-analytics

i wish you could help with my strange problem. Well I tried to add pageviews on my blog so i deployed google-analytics-super-proxy and now I need to make a right query, but this [site](https://ga-dev-tools.web.app) has only ua and ga4, and i cannot make a request.

I need to make a query like

```
 https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A12445&start-date={6daysago}&end-date={today}
```

I tried to do it manually, but i don't know ids

Comment: Adding pageviews to your blog has nothing to do with the google-analytics-super-proxy. If you just want to track pageviews, you must deploy the code that is shown to you during creation of the Google Analytics account/property. It's unclear what you need. Describe your situation better.

Comment: @BNazaruk, i use a jekyll theme where pageviews provides [link](https://chirpy.cotes.info/posts/enable-google-pv/), but i stucked on making query anyway

Comment: making what query? Please clearly elaborate in the question what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @BNazaruk I'm sorry for misunderstanding. I'm trying to make query which will be scheduled with superProxy. I want query to tell me views about all my posts. But now making query is more difficult due to google update. I don't know where I can build my query correctly. Now (GA4) query explorer shows only json version of query, but superProxy expects a usual link. Do you know how to make usual link query in old style?

Comment: For your analytics tracking, you likely either use GA4 or GA UA analytics. It's obvious from the tracking codes (property ids). UA always has UA in front of the code. GA4 doesn't have it. Go to your GA property, or look at your GA payloads and look for the tracking code there. If you look at the network request, then you need to look at the tid field.

Comment: @BNazaruk, So there is no old interface which can help me to make query.